# Slide menu with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, menuitem, slide

I'm trying to create a new menu with job listings for my wordpress page, like the one on this page: http://www.resume.se/, where it says *Senaste jobben* (sorry for it being in Swedish, hope you get which menu I'm referring to). So, I want the list object to be visible for a few seconds, and then I want the menu slide to the left, the first time the width of the first list object, the second slide the width of the second list object, and so on.

```
if ($('.container-menu-platsannonser').length > 0 ) {

    var slider = $('.menu-platsannonser').children('ul');
    speed = 4000;

    slider.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var li = $this.find('li');
        var no_of = li.length;
        var cur = 1;

        if (3 < no_of) {
            $this.slideShow = function() {
                ++cur;
                $this.animate({
                    'margin-left': '-='+100

                }, 600, 'swing', function(){
                    if (no_of == cur) {
                        $this.css('margin-left', '0');
                        cur = 1;
                    }
                    setTimeout($this.slideShow, speed);
                })
            }
            setTimeout($this.slideShow, speed);
        }
    })


}
```

I've managed to set the slide to 100 px, but how do I get the animation width to change with each list item? Also, right now I have four menu items, created with wordpress. This code makes the list items slide two and a half time, and then it starts from the beginning. I would like the menu to loop seamlessly. Bear with me on this, since I kinda suck at javascript. Please, let me know if I'm being unclear, or if you need additional information.
So, to sum up. What I'd like to do is:

– Slide the menu to the left, the width of the list object

– Keep on looping endlessly

Appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 0):

To get the width on the list item I think you can just use:

```
$("li:fist").outerWidth(true);
```

To keep the loop going forever I would wait for the animation to complete and move the li to the end of the list.

```
var $li = $("li:first");
$li.parent().append($li);
```